# Redireccionamiento desde un servlet a un JSP

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets, get

He creado un servlet en un proyecto cuyo Context Path es `/Indi` y la ruta relativa es home. Cuando se accede a este servlet, por defecto hacemos

```
dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/vistas/Inicio.jsp");
```

Pero dentro de esta vista, hay dos botones, los cuales en función de la acción, quiero que me redirija a otro `.jsp`.

```
String action = request.getServletPath();
System.out.println("Accion: " + action);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;

// JSP que se muestra inicialmente
dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/vistas/Inicio.jsp");

// Lógica para la acción proporcionada por los botones
if ("verMenuCompleto".equals(action)) {
// "Ver menú completo" (GET)
dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/vistas/menuCompleto.jsp");
} else if ("login".equals(action)) {
// "LOGIN" (GET)
dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/vistas/login.jsp");
}


// Reenvía la solicitud al JSP correspondiente
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
@WebServlet(name = "home", urlPatterns = {"/home", "/reserva", "/verMenuCompleto", "/login"})

<form action="/home/verMenuCompleto" method="GET">
<button class="btnVerMenuCompleto" style="color:#2c3e50;">Ver menú completo</button>
</form>
```

De esta forma, al hacer click sobre el button, me sale error 404, en lugar de la vista jsp establecida. ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: Quizás [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11779721/2553194) te ayude.